# Enthought Canopy Mayavi font size bug

Tags: python, enthought, mayavi, canopy, mayavi.mlab

The font size setting in Enthough Canopy Mayavi mlab appears to be broken.

Neither the command:

`mlab.axes.label_text_property.font_size = 12 (e.g.)`

nor the direct menu font size command (advanced settings) works.

I have logged a bug report with Enthought, but it looks like a more general Mayavi bug, see

[Does Mayavi "Font Size" text property work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077984/does-mayavi-font-size-text-property-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you say this is a bug that has to do with the translation between the mayavi layer and the vtk layer.  But for now you could use this attribute:

```
>> ax=mlab.axes()
>> ax.axes.font_factor
1.5
>> ax.axes.font_factor=2
```

It only produces a small increase in size, though, as it rejects values above 2.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job perfectly. Setting the font_factor to 1.0 gets the font size exactly right for my purpose.